# Prediction of a MA(1) process

Tags: statistics, time-series

[image]

I was reading the book of Hamilton, time series analysis. I don't understand why in passage $4.2.3$ he expands the geometric serie with alternate signs. Shouldn't the expansion be done only with positive signs?

Answer (score 1):

Please take into account that the series development in which all signs of the expansion are positive corresponds to $\frac{1}{(1-\theta)}$, so in this case the expansion is on $\frac{1}{(1-(-\theta))}$ and thus the alternate signs corresponding to $(-\theta)^i$